# Нессколько mysql запросов в одном

Tags: php, mysqli

Подскажите,  пожалуйсста, как вывести посты, которые пользователь добавил  в избранное?

Есть две таблицы. 1:

```
CREATE TABLE `likes` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `userid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `postid` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

И 2:

```
CREATE TABLE `post` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `image` text NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `author` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `views` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `likes` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Пробовал вот так:

```
$author = $row['id'];
$sql = "SELECT likes.postid, likes.userid
        FROM likes WHERE likes.userid = '$author'
        LEFT JOIN post ON post.id = likes.userid";

while ($post = $sql->fetch_assoc()) {
     echo $post['id'];
}
```

Но не получилось. Заранее, спассибо.

Comment: как всегда, вопрос "несколько запросов в одном", внутри, внезапно, запрос уже один(!), а вся проблема в том что  запрос забыли выполнить.

Comment: Также стоит заметить, что джойн ид поста - ид юзера не является правильным.

Comment: @Ипатьев Так его не "забыли" выполнить, а не смогли - по причине синтаксической ошибочности.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Сам разобрался.

```
$author = $row['id'];
$sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM likes l, post p WHERE l.userid = $author AND p.id = l.postid");

while ($post = $sql->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $post['id'];
}
```